# (Spotify Web API) Create New Playlist - POST request returning 'Error 403 (Forbidden)'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, spotify

Here is the link to the Web API notes on how to create a new playlist. https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/create-playlist/

As far as I understand, the POST requests the url `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists`. This is requested while passing the access token and data. The content type of the data being 'application/json'.

For some reason this is failing and returning a Error **403 (Forbidden)** in the console.

Anything I'm missing?

```js
//(playlistName, userId, accessToken) are passed to this.

var urlString = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + userId + '/playlists';

var jsonData = {
  "name": playlistName,
  "public": false
};

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: urlString,
  data: jsonData,
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
  },
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(result) {
    console.log('Woo! :)');
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('Error! :(');
  }
})
```

Comment: Please check your OAuth token. The rest seems to be fine on first glance.

Comment: Hey :) 

I am able to create a playlist by using their example. This is with using my Owner Id, Playlist name, and the oAuth Token that I'm using for the Ajax request. 

I've just tried to see if changing the content type to 'contentType: application/json; charset=utf-8' would do anything with no luck.

It seems to work fine on their example. But not through an Ajax POST. (I'm still getting the 403 Error). Did you get it to work? 

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tried your example, I get a `401 unauthorized` when filling in bogus data. So you are authorized, but the API really does not grant you the rights (`403 forbidden`).

Please have a look at the authorization guide. I am pretty sure, your error is there. Especially have a look at `scope`. You might simply not grant enough power in the login. And therefore ending up with only public access, which does not include adding playlists.

I cite form the API docs:

> To be able to create private playlists, the user must have granted the
>   `playlist-modify-private` scope.

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

Comment: Works now! I messed up when generating the oAuth token and the 'playlist-modify-private' was not being included correctly. Now that it has been added it's working as expected! Thanks for narrowing it down and helping out :)